# Render js template through php using mustache

Tags: php, javascript, mustache, mustache.php

I am using [mustache PHP](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) to render my html files and everything works correctly except in one case. There is a situation where I load an html file through an ajax call following this structure:

**PHP** - renders -> **HTML** - javascript appends -> **HTML 2nd file**

What I would like to do is to get the mustache parameters into the HTML 2nd file, as some data is generated in the initial PHP file and I wouldn't like to make another call to retrieve this data again.

- Do I need *mustache js* version for this ?
- How can I get the data from the PHP in js by using **mustache**?
- And how can I get the PHP rendered variables in the HTML 2nd file ?

What I can do is to insert hidden inputs to get the data from them in javascript but I would really like to avoid this practice. I don't like this practice as user can easily modify the inputs.

Any idea??

Comment: I need a solution for this but it seems nobody knows an answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I found a solution for this. Print the output of a php file on an ajax call.

```
Mustache_Autoloader::register();
$m = new Mustache_Engine(array(
     'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader('./templates/')
));
echo $m->render('templatename', $o);
```

and then using .html(data); with jQuery

Comment: Hey, I am also looking for a solution for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556684/how-to-show-an-activity-that-a-user-made-inside-a-javascript-that-shows-a-notifi if you have time can you please check it? But please also check the link in Edit 1#, I explained all my process. Yet I'm stuck at gathering them all together. I'd be really glad if you could check...Thanks!